# MacOS doesn't fit external screen and I don't know how to stretch it

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

Model: MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012)

Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

Monitor: Samsung U28E590D 28-Inch UHD

Using HDMI cable to connect to the monitor.

Things I have tried:

- Option + click to see all the possible resolutions
- Reset NVRAM
- Reset SMC
- Using SwitchResX
- Playing the the monitor's settings

Nothing works! I have absolutely no idea how to fit the OS to the screen. The text also looks a little blurry.

How it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0djDt.jpg

Help on fixing this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't

If you have a look at the [specs on the monitor](https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/samsung-uhd-28-monitor-with-high-glossy-black-finish-lu28e590ds-za/) It's a 4K monitor 3840 x 2160.

Then have a peek at the specs on your computer. I usually use [EveryMac.com.](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-late-2012-retina-display-specs.html)

And under Second display support on the second link above it says:

> *This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support
> a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single display
> up to 1920x1200 via HDMI. Although it can theoretically power all
> three external displays, as confirmed by a helpful reader, it runs too
> hot with three displays connected.

To me that says your Mac does not support the highest resolution of that monitor, so you are going to get a resolution that is lower and of poorer quality.

You need to get a monitor that supports 2560 x 1600 native resolution for optimal display output.